# How do I change that which is inherited by stdout=None in subrocess.Popen(stdout=None)?

Tags: python, subprocess

Why is this?

```
>>> sys.stdout=open("/dev/null", "w")
>>> subprocess.Popen(["echo", "foobar"], stdout=None)
foobar
```

I was expecting output to not appear, but begone. Documentation says `stdout=None` is to inherit handles from the parent.

Martijn says, that the assignment to `sys.stdout` does not change the handle that is inherited.

Then what is that `handle` and how do I change it, so that it is inherited by the subprocess call with `stdtout=None`, and both parent and subprocess output go to the same place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the parent process handle does **not** go to `/dev/null`. You did not change the process handle, you only rebound the Python `sys.stdout` to point to an new file object.

And you can still find the original `sys.stdout` object under `sys.__stdout__`, by the way, and that object is really just a wrapper to translate Python string objects to characters to write to the actual file handle in C.

The actual process handle is a file descriptor number, and the OS directs that file descriptor for the process. To change that handle from Python, you'll have to do some file descriptor juggling with `os.close()` and `os.dup2()` calls:

```
import os

def freopen(filename, mode, fobj):
    new = open(filename, mode)
    newfd = new.fileno()
    targetfd = fobj.fileno()
    os.close(targetfd)
    os.dup2(newfd, targetfd)
```

then use:

```
freopen('/dev/null', 'w', sys.stdout)
```

It'll be **much easier** to just pass the file object directly to the `subprocess` however:

```
with open("/dev/null", "w") as devnull:
    subprocess.Popen(["echo", "foobar"], stdout=devnull)
```

Comment: I am sorry I can't find any documentation as to what the Python "process handle" is, can you point me to it?  I thought, that it meant `sys.stdout` from inside the Python script, and if I change that (and I can revert back to `sys.__stdout__` I know that), then I have just changed the "handle".

Comment: OK, this is all good, but then I don't understand, why after `sys.stdout=open("/dev/null", "w")` call, all output from the process goes away?

Comment: Everything *in Python* uses the `sys.stdout` object, but child processes don't know about that object and can only see the C-level original filehandle.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.stdout` is just a python object; the real magic happens at the file descriptor/description level, that can be manipulated using the `os` module

Theoretically you could direct the file descriptor 1 to another file by doing:

```
 sys.stdout.flush()
 fd = os.open("/dev/null", "w")
 sys.stdout = os.fdopen(fd, "w")
 os.dup2(fd, 1)
 os.close(fd)
```

Though I do not guarantee that it would do what you want in all cases; better just give `subprocess.Popen` a new Python file for stdout, something like:

```
null = open("/dev/null", "w")
subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=null)
null.close()
```

The default `None` for `stdout`  really stands for inherit (do not do anything for the open files). Since `sys.stdout.fileno()` is usually `1` (unless something really fishy is going on), this is often effectively the same as `stdout=sys.stdout`.